# Finding the length of an integer with switch in C or C++

Tags: c++

I want to find the length of an integer in C or C++ by using a switch statement I know there are other simple ways but I want use this method for some reasons so here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

main() {
int a,length;
std::cout << "Please enter a number:\n";
std::cin >> a;
if(a<0)
    a=-a;
switch(a){
case 1<...<10:length==1,break;
case 10<...<100:length==2,break;
case 100<...<1000:length==3,break;
}
std::cout << "It has "<< length <<" numbers\n"; 
getch();    
}
```

So , I dont know what I can use instead of cases.

Comment: Looks like incomplete homework for me. Take a look at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm (for example)

Comment: You can't switch on arbitrary comparisons, so you're going to have to want to do something else. A switch is essentially a sequence of equality comparisons.

Comment: A switch is designed as a simplified version of the if-else statement using only direct comparisons. Thats why you can't use it like that. Use the normal if-else statements.

Comment: @arc_lupus I always wonder why low-qualified programmers so bother that somebody tries to do his homework! Can you explain me this phenomenon?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: If you target me with "low-qualified programmer": Yes, that is true, but I thought that SO is not a page where you ask things without first taking a look at the implementation and definition...

Comment: @arc_lupus Maybe it would be more useful for you to spend your time learning C and C++ instead of bothering about questions of others. What do you think about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the GCC extension,  can be described as follows.

```
switch(a){
case 1 ... 9     : length = 1; break;
case 10 ... 99   : length = 2; break;
case 100 ... 999 : length = 3; break;
}
```

Comment: Nice. And if `length==1,break;` is also a GCC extension then OP's code barely contains any random construction at all!

Comment: Tnx ... i thought this can help but i tried it and it returns 0 for all numbers ... any suggestions ??

Comment: @MajidAmiri change your code like this. `length==1,break;` --> `length = 1 ; break;`

Comment: tnx ... it completely works <3 and some friends understand that nothing is impossible in computer world !!

Comment: @MajidAmiri   if this is homework, then using non-standard language exceptions won't get you far...

Comment: Thanks! This syntax works for Arduino IDE too.

Answer (score 2):

It is tempting to use a series of `if` statements like

```
if (a >= 10000){
    length = 5;
} else if (/* And so on
```

But this requires you to make assumptions about the possible maximum *size* of an `int`. This is not defined by C or C++, although the minimum possible range is [-32767 to +32767].

Some compilers allow you to use a *range-based* `switch` but this is (i) not standard C or C++, and (ii) you'll still encounter the problem with possible range above.

A better approach is to repeatedly divide your `int` by 10 and count the number of times you can do that until you reach zero. And don't forget to test your work with a negative number and an initial value of 0.

Computing the base-10 logarithm is problematic due to the computation taking place in floating point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach with the switch statement. Though in my demonstrative program I use only the label `default` you may include any case label that corresponds to the enumeration

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while ( true )
    {        
        enum : unsigned int { One = 1, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine } digits;

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): ";

        unsigned int x = 0;
        std::cin >> x;

        if ( !x ) break;

        int len;


        switch ( ( digits = One,   x < 10 ) ||
                 ( digits = Two,   x < 100 ) ||
                 ( digits = Three, x < 1000 ) ||
                 ( digits = Four,  x < 10000 ) ||
                 ( digits = Five,  x < 100000 ) ||
                 ( digits = Six,   x < 1000000 ) ||
                 ( digits = Seven, x < 10000000 ) ||
                 ( digits = Eight, x < 100000000 ) ||
                 ( digits = Nine,  x < 1000000000 ), digits )
        {
                default:
                    len = digits;
                    break;
        }

        std::cout << x << " has " << len << " digits." << std::endl;
    }        
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 1
1 has 1 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 11
11 has 2 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 111
111 has 3 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 1111
1111 has 4 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 11111
11111 has 5 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 111111
111111 has 6 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 1111111
1111111 has 7 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 11111111
11111111 has 8 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 111111111
111111111 has 9 digits.
Enter a non-negative number (0-exit): 0
```

An alternative representation of the switch including other case labels

```
    switch ( ( digits = One,   x < 10 ) ||
             ( digits = Two,   x < 100 ) ||
             ( digits = Three, x < 1000 ) ||
             ( digits = Four,  x < 10000 ) ||
             ( digits = Five,  x < 100000 ) ||
             ( digits = Six,   x < 1000000 ) ||
             ( digits = Seven, x < 10000000 ) ||
             ( digits = Eight, x < 100000000 ) ||
             ( digits = Nine,  x < 1000000000 ), digits )
    {
        case One:
            std::cout << "You could enter more digits.." << std::endl;
        case Two: case Three: case Four: case Five: case Six: case Seven: case Eight:
            len = digits;
            break;
        case Nine:
            std::cout << "Do you like money?" << std::endl;
            len = digits;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Too big number! It can be never" << std::endl;
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `switch` for that purpose.Use `if-else` statements instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int a,length;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number:\n";
    std::cin >> a;
    if(a<0)
        a=-a;
    if( a >= 1 && a < 10 )
        length = 1;
    else if( a >= 10 && a < 100 )
        length = 2;
    /* .............. */

    std::cout << "It has "<< length <<" numbers\n"; 
    getch();    
}
```

Comment: i said i knew there are other ways and i knew how to use `if-else` statement but i wanted to know if there is any way i can use `switch` statement ... tnx for ur help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use comparisons in switch case. I would recommend a series of if else if in this case with progressively lower limits:

```
if (a >= 100) length = 3;
else if (a >= 10) length = 2;
else length = 1;
```

Add as many as needed for the number of digits you want to handle.

Also note you have to assign to `length`. When you are doing `length==1` you are returning a boolean value.

Comment: @machine_1 and for your specific comment the OP seems to be interested only for numbers with no more than 3 digits. According to the code in his question. Of course the series of if-else need to cover the desired range whatever that is.